# why memory size of an array of hashes is increasing after sorting ? (In Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

**why memory size of an array of hashes is increasing after sorting ?**

lets say, there is an array of hashes. if we check memory size of that array, its returning a value is 44.
Now If i apply sort on that array, then its memory size is increased now.

```
require 'objspace'
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>1}, {:a=>1, :b=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>1, :b=>6}, {:a=>1, :b=>7}]
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(array)
>> 44
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(array.sort_by{|x| -x[:b]})
>> 68
sorted_array = array.sort_by{|x| -x[:b]}
>> [{:a=>1, :b=>7}, {:a=>1, :b=>6}, {:a=>1, :b=>4}, {:a=>1, :b=>3}, {:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>1, :b=>1}]
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(sorted_array)
>> 68
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of):

> Return consuming memory size of obj.
>
> Note that the return size is incomplete. You need to deal with this information as only a **HINT.** Especially, the size of `T_DATA` may not be correct.

If you'd like to dig deeper and understand *why* the value is only a "hint", then [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e33b1690d06f867e45750bd8e3e8b06d78b5bc26/gc.c#L3212-L3330) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6b818dd9616ce6f0c849ab32c5869cc55b624b0a/array.c#L570-L579) would be a good starting point.